# Using Spark (MLlib) with Spray: how to integrate both?

Tags: apache-spark, spray

My intent is to create an App using Akka. As soon as I realized I needed to create some Web Services I decided to use Spray.

This App needs a classifier, so I built a prototype with MLlib on Spark. Now I need to understand how to integrate Spark with Spray. Specifically I need to get
1. which is the best approach to create the Spark Context
2. how to make the spark context visible to an Actor

I Suppose that I have to create the Spark context while bootstrapping the App, so I modified this code from an example on [GitHub](https://github.com/eigengo/activator-akka-spray) that was for a Spray App with no Spark integration. As a result I got an error when instantiating the Actor

```
14/10/11 22:12:32 ERROR actor.OneForOneStrategy: exception during creation
akka.actor.ActorInitializationException: exception during creation
```

My changes to the original code are those marked with `//$$$ $$$`

```
trait Core {

  protected implicit def system: ActorSystem
  // $$$ SparkContext in the trait $$$
  protected implicit def sc: SparkContext

}

/**
 * This trait implements ``Core`` by starting the required 
 * ``ActorSystem`` and registering the
 * termination handler to stop the system when the JVM exits.
 */
trait BootedCore extends Core with Api {
  def system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("activator-akka-spray")
  def actorRefFactory: ActorRefFactory = system
  // $$$ Initializing SparkContext $$$
  def sc = new SparkContext("local[2]", "naivebayes")  

  val rootService = system.actorOf(Props(new RoutedHttpService(routes)))

  IO(Http)(system) ! Http.Bind(rootService, "0.0.0.0", port = 9010)

  /**
   * Construct the ActorSystem we will use in our application
   */
  //protected implicit  val system : ActorSystem

  /**
   * Ensure that the constructed ActorSystem is shut 
   * down when the JVM shuts down
   */
  sys.addShutdownHook(system.shutdown())

}

/**
 * This trait contains the actors that make up our application;
 * it can be mixed in with
 * ``BootedCore`` for running code or ``TestKit`` 
 * for unit and integration tests.
 */
trait CoreActors {
  this: Core =>
                           //$$$ passing the context to the actor $$$
  val classifier = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[ClassifierActor], sc)) 

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just found out the error was due to different Akka version used by Spark and Spray.

== UPDATE ==
If I'm not wrong, the problem was fixed just by removing Akka from my project dependencies in build.sbt so that I could use the specific Akka version Spark depends on.
I just let Spark choose for me what Akka version to use.
Then I searched for a version of spray that depends on the same version of Akka on which Spark depends on.

Spark 1.1.0
Spray 1.2.2

I've never updated to earlier versions so I cannot say which versions of both can fit together if you want to stay up-to-date.

Comment: Could you please show how you solved this (a git repo would be great but even versions would help) -- I am running into the same issue. I am trying with val akkaVersion  = "2.3.9"
   val sprayVersion = "1.2-20130727" 
   val sparkVersion = "1.2.1" but after including the spark jars I am getting errors like java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: akka.actor.Props$.apply(Lscala/Function0;)Lakka/actor/Props;

Comment: Do you have git repo for the above ? I am working on something similar - integrating spray with Spark, I am not sure how to do it.Thanks